# Android loadimage from URL having redirects issue

Tags: android

Previously I have posted a question on loading images from a url in Android. I noticed that for some urls it returns "Error 404".

It is due to URL redirects. Any idea how do I overcome this?

The previous question and accepted answer can be found here:
[File not found exception when displaying image from a url in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394650/file-not-found-exception-when-displaying-image-from-a-url-in-android/19395710#19395710)

Is there any other way to work around the URL redirects issue?

Comment: Can you please share your code to understand where the problem is in code?

Comment: @Nikki The code is in the link above.

Comment: Check answer given. Is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you found this issue that means, url which is you are calling , that location is removed or not present on your server database. It may be removed or you are using wrong path. Just check that once and try.

Comment: Tried already, I could actually load the urls in a desktop web browser. But when i tried on Android, it fails for some urls. Could be due to url redirects but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: This issue is not from Android side, or you can use AndroidQuery to cross check if thats working or not. Which loading method are you using?

Comment: I am using imageview and setImageBitmap to load the image.

Comment: Dont use it, use Android Query, have you ever heard about it?

Comment: Yes, but have not used it before. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the url you are sending on server to download contains "http" or not. If it doesn't contain then append it in starting of url as "http://".

```
if(!URL.contains"http")
     URL= "http://"+URL;
```